# What is the right way to line break on return typing hint

Tags: python, conventions

Say I have code like this:

```py
def on_test_end(self, test_dict: Dict[str, Union[Tensor, List[str]]])):
    """
    optionally override for postprocessing of test outputs
    expect test dict to contain 'outputs' and maybe 'id'
    """
    return test_dict
```

That fits nicely the recommended width of approx 80 characters. But when I add the return type:

```py
def on_test_end(self, test_dict: Dict[str, Union[Tensor, List[str]]]) -> Dict[str, Union[Tensor, List[str]]]):
    """
    optionally override for postprocessing of test outputs
    expect test dict to contain 'outputs' and maybe 'id'
    """
    return test_dict
```

it doesn't fit. So where should the line break go here?

Comment: Not an answer to the actual question, but maybe define `Union[Tensor, List[str]]` or the entire `Dict[...]` as a separate type?

Comment: Yeah it would make the code look much nicer, but somehow less readable as I would then need to do it for a bunch of other things, and the reader would have to go back and forth to reference

Comment: @AlexanderSoare most html doc generators like `pdoc` resolve aliased types, so the reader would not have to search for the reference.